# Combinatorics: How many people speak German, French, English and Portuguese?

Tags: combinatorics

In a group of $32$ persons, $20$ speak German, $16$ speak French, $26$ speak English, and $16$ speak Portuguese.

Every person in this group speaks at least one of these four languages.

How can I determine the minimum/maximum number of persons in the group, that speak all four languages?

To structure this a bit:

- $ U = 32$ persons
- $G = 20$ German
- $F = 16$ French
- $E = 26$ English
- $P = 16$ Portuguese

For the minimum, can I say:

$U -G = 32 - 20 = 12$ persons who don't speak German.

$U-F = 32 - 16 = 16$ persons who don't speak French.

$U-E = 32 - 26 = 6$ persons who don't speak English.

$U-P = 32 - 16 = 16$ persons who don't speak Portuguese.

Together: $\min\{12, 16, 6, 16\}$, leading to a minimum of $6$ persons, who speak all four languages.

And for the maximum then $\max\{12, 16, 6, 16\}$, leading to a maximum of $16$ persons, who speak all four languages.

I don't know if that is correct..

Comment: If 16 speak all languages, it means that there are 16 who speak at least 1, at most 3. Since there are only 16 French and 16 Portuguese speakers, it means that only 4 Germans are left who don't speak those two languages, and 10 English. Those add up to 14, not 16.

Comment: Also, assume that no Portuguese can speak French or no French can speak Portuguese. That's a valid configuration, so there is no one who can speak all four languages.

Comment: Might help to consider the generalized inclusion/exclusion principle:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle

Comment: @Andrei So you are saying that the minimum is $0$ and the maximum $14$? Regarding the minimum I thought the same first, but is it really that "simple"?

Comment: The notation PRT is a bit clumsy.  I suggest renaming the whole group with another capital letter, such as U, which stands for a universal set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum is clearly $0$: $16$ people speak French but not Portuguese, and the other $16$ speak Portuguese but not French. Distribute the English and German speakers however you please.

It's not hard to see that the maximum cannot be $16$: if it were, then the F and P speakers would be the same set of $16$, and $16$ of the $26$ G and $16$ of the $20$ E would have to be that same set of $16$ people. But that leaves a maximum of  $16+(26-16)+(20-16) = 30$ people.

That suggests decreasing the overlap between F and P by one: assume there are $15$ people speaking F and P, and 15 of the G and 15 of the E also speak F and P. That gives $16 + (16-15) + (26-15) + (20-15) = 33$ people. So if one of the G speakers that doesn't speak F also speaks E, you get to 32.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: min. 0, max. 15

I would like to elaborate on this answer.
To find out the least no. of people who speak all 4 languages, let us try finding the average no. of languages spoken by one person. 
Each language counts as one point per person, therefore, 20 German speakers, 16 French speakers, 26 English speakers and 16 Portuguese speakers give us a total of (20+16+26+16)=78 language points. These are divided among 32 people, hence the average person speaks 78/32=39/16 which is approximately equal to 2.44 languages.
Since this number comes out to be less than 3, we can assume that the minimum no. of people who speak all four languages could be 0 for a suitable distribution of trilingual, bilingual and monolingual people, as say if the average no. of languages spoken was 3.2(something between 3 and 4) then there had to be some people who spoke all four languages to bring the average above 3.
Now, to verify the same, 
If there are-
 16 people who speak English, German and French,
 4 people who speak English, German and Portuguese,
 6 people who speak English and Portuguese,
 and 6 people who only speak Portuguese,
We get a total of 32 people, with 26 English speakers, 16 French, 20 German and 16 who speak Portuguese.

For the case of Maximum no. of speakers who speak all 4 languages, if we let 16 people, speak all 4 languages, (16 because, there can't be 17 or more since French speaking and Portuguese speaking people are only 16 in number),  there will be 10 remaining English speakers and 4 German speakers. Even if these people were monolingual, the total would be 30.
So, we see that for 15 people who speak all 4 languages, it would bring that to 15 4x speakers , which leaves 18 language points I.e at most 18 people(if all of them are monolingual) giving a total of 33, if we change one person to be bilingual instead of monolingual, we see the beautiful number 32. So, 15 people who speak all 4 languages and 1 person who speaks 2 languages makes for (15*4+1*2)=62 language points, leaving (78-62)=16 language points, which if divided among monolinguals, gives 32.